# Remove even numbers from queue

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue, nodes

I got stuck when trying to remove even number from queue in C programming. Here is the code:

My data structure for Queue:

```
typedef struct _listnode
{
    int data;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode; // You should not change the definition of ListNode

typedef struct _linkedlist
{
    int size;
    ListNode *first;
} LinkedList;   // You should not change the definition of LinkedList

typedef struct _queue
{
    LinkedList list;
} Queue;
```

And I am calling from my main:

```
case 3:
        deleteEven(&q); // You need to code this function
        printf("Result:\n");
        printList(&q.list);
        break;
```

What I am trying to do is first, I tried to check if the queue is empty. Then I will get the linked list head and modulus with 2, if getting 0 means it's even number and then I will dequeue it from the queue.

However, with these code, when I try to dequeue even numbers from queue, it just stopped working and not showing any error message.

Anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `deleteEven`'s `while` loop you do this -

```
free(odd->list.first->data);                    //problem 1
odd->list.first->data= odd->list.first->next;   //problem 2- assigning pointer type to int
```

**Problem 1-** But you haven't allocated memory to `odd->list.first->data` , it is an integer variable. And if you try to `free` such thing can cause error in your program (*you should not* `free` *memory not allocated by* `malloc` *or similar functions*)

You allocate memory to `odd` , so `free` pointer `odd`.

Even you should not `free` inside your `while` loop, as you allocate memory only one time .

**Problem 2** - You assign pointer type to `int`. That's may also be one of reason for this error .

You should write loop like this -

```
while (!isEmptyQueue(odd)) {
    enqueue(que, odd->list.first->data);
    odd->list.first= odd->list.first->next;      // increment pointer 
}
free(odd);
```

**3.** While calling function `dequeue` -

```
 dequeue(que->list.first->data);
```

`int` is passed but it expects `Queue *` .

Its type is `int`  but you return `NULL` from it (return `-1` or something to show failure).

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by old? And how should I fix it?

Comment: @20Cents Ohh, sorry I meant `odd` there . Edited it .

Comment: But even if I cancelled out that line, the program still crashes. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @20Cents Yes you were also assigning pointe type to `int` in your loop , I have edited it . Take a look please .

Comment: Unfortunately, nope. The program still crashes

Comment: @20Cents Right now I don't see problem in that function . In `enqueue` function it works correct right  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93865/discussion-between-20-cents-and-ameycu).